# how to display a tooltip number over an imageView (like in notification)

Tags: android, notifications, imageview, tooltip

Is there an easy way to display a tooltip on an imageview looking the same that the number tooltip on a notification icon?
There are no 'number' attribute in ImageView.
Is there another simple way to display a number in a tooltip over an imageview?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Put the `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`.

Step #2: Put a `TextView` in the same `RelativeLayout`, as a later child than the `ImageView`.

Step #3: Give the `TextView` an appropriate background and text.

Step #4: Give the `TextView` the `android:layout_` attributes you want to position it where you want.

`RelativeLayout` allows for stacking on the Z axis -- later children float over top of earlier children. And, `RelativeLayout` allows you to position the `TextView` in, say, the lower-right corner.

Comment: ok, so no built-in easy way to do it like with the notification ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005) a good solution!

Setup `ImageView` content description (in xml or in the code) and use static methods from `CheatSheet.java`.